# Enable/disable syntax highlight in QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt

So, I'm writing a simple code editor in C++ and Qt. I have managed to create some syntax highlighting (SH) rules by using the QSyntaxHighlighter class.
Now, I want to enable and disable this feature. To enable SH on a QTextEdit, I have a pointer:

```
SyntaxHighlight *highlighter;
highlighter = new SyntaxHighlight(editor->document());
```

All I have to do, is somehow make this pointer point to nothing. But I have tried to make it point to NULL and 0 without any result. Have also creates a deconstructor, and used `delete highlighter`. Nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Please let me know if I should supply more code.

Comment: Random thought - maybe you have to redraw QTextEdit widget after deleting SyntaxHighlight?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that. 2 problems. 1: didn't work :) 2: if I redraw it to, for instance, black, then it will still continue to color the text after I redraw it.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than trying to delete the highlighter, you should use:

```
highlighter->setDocument(0);
```

**Edit:** Deleting the highlighter also works, so you have probably inadvertently set another `QSyntaxHighlighter` on the document, or you are not disabling or deleting the correct one.

Because the syntax highlighter installs itself as a child of the document, you can retrieve  it / them with `findChild` / `findChildren`:

```cpp
foreach(QSyntaxHighlighter* highlighter,
        ui->textEdit->findChildren<QSyntaxHighlighter*>()) {
    delete highlighter;
}
```

Comment: Still didn't work. The previous colors stay the same, and if I continue to write in the same document, the SH rules are still intact.